# Extract subnational division from string and convert it into country name in R

Tags: r, country-codes

I have a series of strings containing only province names/subnational division names that I want converted into a country name vector in R. It's relatively easy to extract country names using the `countrycode` package, but I don't see a way to convert province names into countries using that package.

For example:

```
provinces <- c("The governor of Florida", "The Premier of Ontario", "Jalisco has a province-wide policy")
```

I am hoping for a method that converts the `provinces` vector into a vector that looks something like `c("United States of America", "Canada", "Mexico")`.

Comment: The [example from the documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/countrycode/man/countrycode.html) gives a list of US states, you could build a worldwide list by scraping [a Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_political_and_geographic_subdivisions_by_total_area_(all)). Then you can also look around, [this file](https://github.com/olahol/iso-3166-2.json/blob/master/iso-3166-2.json) seems to contain everything you might need.

Comment: @Alexlok, thanks for the advice on using a custom dictionary. I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the above comment, I realized that you could use a custom dictionary in `countrycode`, which allows you to incorporate subnational data.

EDIT:

Here is a fully reproducible example as the last didn't fully work:

```
require(countrycode)
require(choroplethrAdmin1)

# example data
provinces <- c("The governor of Florida", "Tim Stevenson leads Oxfordshire", "Gobierno del Estado de Hidalgo")

# remove punctuation
provinces <- gsub("[[:punct:]\n]", "", provinces)

# load administrative division dictionary
data(admin1.regions)

# remove duplicate region names (countrycode function only accepts unique names)
admin1.regions <- admin1.regions[!duplicated(admin1.regions$region),]

# convert provinces to country
provinces_to_country <- countrycode(provinces, "region", "country", custom_dict = admin1.regions, origin_regex = TRUE)
```

OLD, NOT REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE:

```
require(countrycode)
require(choroplethrAdmin1)

# example data
provinces <- c("The governor of Florida", "The Premier of Ontario", "Jalisco has a province-wide policy")

# remove punctuation
provinces <- gsub("[[:punct:]\n]", "", provinces)

# load administrative division dictionary
data(admin1.regions)

# remove duplicate region names (countrycode function only accepts unique names)
admin1.regions <- admin1.regions[!duplicated(admin1.regions$region),]

# convert provinces to country
provinces_to_country <- countrycode(provinces, "region", "country", custom_dict = admin1.regions, origin_regex = TRUE)
```

Comment: Just to point out why 2 out of 3 of your examples fail to match: 
1. 'The Premier of Ontario' matches two subdivisions, 'ontario' and 'mie'
2. 'Jalisco has a province-wide policy' does not match how it is listed in the subdivisions 'estado de jalisco'

Comment: @CJYetman, I suppose you could just manually change the dictionary to make it work... I'm not aware of another dictionary with these administrative divisions that would be better, unfortunately. No perfect solution.

Comment: Or... it would probably be a better strategy to “clean” the data first by extracting just the place name from the phrase/sentence. That would make it easier on whatever system is recognizing the place names. Duplicates will definitely occur in a worldwide place name database, and that’s difficult to work around without additional information.