# Using XML2 to produce a dataframe from a PubMed XML

Tags: r, magrittr, xml2, pubmed

I have already had some help producing this code:

```
library( xml2 )
library( magrittr )

#read the xml-data
doc <- xml2::read_xml( "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=20301425&retmode=xml" )

pmid    <- xml2::xml_find_first( doc, ".//PMID") %>% xml2::xml_text()
authors <- paste( 
  xml2::xml_find_all( doc, ".//AuthorList[@Type = 'authors']/Author/LastName") %>% xml2::xml_text(),
  xml2::xml_find_all( doc, ".//AuthorList[@Type = 'authors']/Author/ForeName") %>% xml2::xml_text(),
  sep = ", " )
affiliate <- xml2::xml_find_all( doc, ".//AuthorList[@Type = 'authors']/Author/AffiliationInfo/Affiliation") %>% xml2::xml_text()

df <- data.frame( pmid = pmid, authors = authors, affiliate = affiliate )
```

This code has created a dataframe, pulling out the information on pmid, author & affiliation. My next question is can you pull out specific information on state/country from the affiliation information to have an additional column in the dataframe containing this information?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wByLx.png)

Comment: Not sure about a universal solution, but usually the last word of the affiliation is the country, except when it's an email address, and often the word before is a State/Province. You could extract these words and use reference tables to see if they match known countries/states, using e.g. `countrycode` and `chloroplethr` as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63528597/extract-subnational-division-from-string-and-convert-it-into-country-name-in-r). By treating a few examples and looking at the results you should be able to determine and solve the common problems.

Comment: @Alexlok Thank you for this! I will continue to have a play around with these options. I was just wondering if you knew of a way to split the affiliate information by their commas? For example: 'Moffitt Cancer Center, Tampa, Florida' Becomes three separate columns in a data frame? Thanks again for your help, I'm still quite new to R!

Comment: Look at `str_split()` (for a vector) and `separate()` (for a column of a df). In base R, there is also `strsplit()` but potentially less practical to use.

Comment: I assume you want the last information (Michigan, Pennsylvania, Florida). You might consider using `stringi::stri_locate_last()` to find the last comma and use `stringr::str_sub()` to get the rest: `df$state <- stringr::str_sub(df$affiliate, start = stringi::stri_locate_last(df$affiliate, fixed = ", ")[, 2] + 1)`